# How to get database connection status inside Azure data factory's data flow?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have created a azure data factory inside which I am using data flow.

This data flow contains multiple operations like to read some files from blobs and read some tables data from azure data base.

My issue is that whenever my dataflow activity trying to read tables from database then I got an error because at that time my database is in pause state.

I searched in net and found that I can check status of azure database by using powershell command but for that I need to create a sperate azure function.

My azure database automatically start if any hit to database. So, I want to do multiple retry to connect with database for certain interval of time and do continue with remaining tasks.

Is there a way to do inside a data flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options for this:
1 - in general, a serverless SQL DB instance takes up to 2 minutes to recover from a paused state so you can add a wait task to your data factory pipeline to wait for 2 minutes between opening the connection and starting the transfer

2 - you can specify a longer timeout for the connection to SQL, this will allow it to wait till the database comes out of paused state.

for the second option, what you need to do is on the connection for SQL database, you can go and add extra connection property called connection timeout and set this to a value of 120+ [image]

Comment: Hi @user7415753 as I'm using DataSet and DataFlow, I am not able to see the second option as per your image. Can you please let me know where can I get this option?

Comment: the properties displayed in option 2 are the properties of the source connection, find this in your data factory (browse through menu on the left and you will find it)

Comment: if you're struggling locating that just let me know and I'll spin up a df instance and take a few screenshots to how to locate it